# Distance between tree levels in Tikz, edges and node centering

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

Level distance does not seem to have any effect on the 1st node's distance from its children in the MWE below (tried adding `level distance` and playing with its values at every level, but it works only for the levelX styles):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape,paper=ansibpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thin,anchor=west, minimum height=2.5em]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    supervisor/.style={%
        edge from parent fork down,
        level distance=2.5cm,
        text centered, text width=5cm},
    teammate/.style={%
        text centered, text width=3cm,
        level distance=2.5cm,
        fill=gray!10},
    subordinate/.style={%
        grow=down, xshift=-1.1cm, % Horizontal position of the child node
        text centered, text width=3cm,
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.205) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
    level1/.style ={level distance=1.5cm},
    level2/.style ={level distance=3cm},
    level3/.style ={level distance=4.5cm},
    level4/.style ={level distance=6cm},
    level5/.style ={level distance=7.5cm},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm}
]
%   \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);

    % Supervisor
    \node[anchor=south,supervisor]{Supervisor\\Supervisory position\\Location}
    [edge from parent fork down]

    % Teammate and Subordinates
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate1\\Position1\\Location1}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate\\Position1\\Location1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Subordinate3}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Subordinate4\\Position4\\Location4}}
        child[subordinate,level5] {node {Subordinate5\\Position5\\Location5}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate2\\Position2\\Location2}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate3\\Position3\\Location3}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate\\two lines}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}     
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Subordinate3}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate4\\Position4\\Location4}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate5\\Position5\\Location5}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {First\\Subordinate}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}};

%\shade[shading=Mandelbrot set] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{This is an org chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Bonus question:** Is it possible to center supervisor's box horisontally?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
level 1/.append style
```

An example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape,paper=ansibpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[draw=black,thin,anchor=west, minimum height=2.5em]

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    supervisor/.style={%
        edge from parent fork down,
        level distance=2.5cm,
        text centered, text width=5cm},
    teammate/.style={%
        text centered, text width=3cm,
        level distance=2.5cm,
        fill=gray!10},
    subordinate/.style={%
        grow=down, xshift=-1.1cm, % Horizontal position of the child node
        text centered, text width=3cm,
        edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.205) |- (\tikzchildnode.west)}},
    level1/.style ={level distance=1.5cm},
    level2/.style ={level distance=3cm},
    level3/.style ={level distance=4.5cm},
    level4/.style ={level distance=6cm},
    level5/.style ={level distance=7.5cm},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
    level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm},
]
%   \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);

    % Supervisor
    \node[anchor=south,supervisor]{Supervisor\\Supervisory position\\Location}
    [edge from parent fork down]

    % Teammate and Subordinates
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate1\\Position1\\Location1}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate\\Position1\\Location1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Subordinate3}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Subordinate4\\Position4\\Location4}}
        child[subordinate,level5] {node {Subordinate5\\Position5\\Location5}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate2\\Position2\\Location2}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate3\\Position3\\Location3}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate\\two lines}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}     
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Subordinate3}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate4\\Position4\\Location4}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {Subordinate1}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}}
    %
    child{node [teammate] {Teammate5\\Position5\\Location5}
        child[subordinate,level1] {node {First\\Subordinate}}
        child[subordinate,level2] {node {Subordinate2}}
        child[subordinate,level3] {node {Third\\Teammate}}
        child[subordinate,level4] {node {Longtext-\\teammate}}};

%\shade[shading=Mandelbrot set] (0,0) rectangle (5,5);
\end{tikzpicture}}
\caption{This is an org chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or this works too: `level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm, level distance=4.5cm}`. Thanks a million!

Comment: @ajeh: `…/.style` does overwrite everything earlier defined stuff. `…/.append style` instead adds/appends (sic!) the new definition(s), only overwriting concurrent options.

Comment: What is level 1 in the MWE? Supervisor or Teammate or something else? Tried moving level 1 style settings into Teammate with no success. Why is level 1 required at all (I borrowed this code from another question here)?

Comment: `level 1/.style` (with a space between "level" and "1") is the same as `level=1, level 1`; it is a style that is automatically executed at the beginning of each set of children, for the level one in the current tree. `level1` (no space) is a user defines style that could be manually applied to any desired node. Perhaps the name choosing for the two styles was not the most appropriate, since it might produce confusion.